# No encuentro o no se crea la carpeta databases en mi proyecto Android Studio con SQLite

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite

Hola buenas tardes con todos, estoy empezando con el desarrollo de aplicaciones móviles en android studio con Sqlite, al momento de ejecutar el siguiente código para la creación de la base de datos no sale algún error pero al mirar los paquetes tampoco visualizo la carpeta databases. será que no lo encuentro o no se ha creado. ayuda por favor. no escribí código en mainactivity.java y no diseñe nada solo el Hello world por defecto, solo lo ejecute después de escribir todo el código.

DBconexion.java

```
package com.android.proyectoconexionsqlite.DB;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBconexion extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "dbPrueba";
    private static final int DB_version = 1;

    public DBconexion(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DBmanager.TABLA_CAMPOS_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DBmanager.TABLA_CAMPOS);
    }
}
```

DBmanager.java

```
package com.android.proyectoconexionsqlite.DB;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DBmanager {
    public static final String TABLA_CAMPOS = "campos.db";
    public static final String CAMPOS_ID = "_id";
    public static final String CAMPOS_CAMPONRO1 = "campo01";
    public static final String CAMPOS_CAMPONRO2 = "campo02";

    public static final String TABLA_CAMPOS_CREATE = "create table campos(_id integer not null, campo01 text not null, campo02 text not null);";

    private DBconexion _conexion;
    private SQLiteDatabase _basededatos;

    public DBmanager(Context context) {
        _conexion = new DBconexion(context);
    }

    public DBmanager open() throws SQLException{
        _basededatos = _conexion.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        _conexion.close();
    }
}
```

Tengo entendido que aquí se tendría que crear la carpeta databases pero nada como puedo solucionar esto, no encuentro alguna solución buscando en internet, gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal es estás definiendo:

```
public static final String TABLA_CAMPOS = "campos.db";
```

debes tomar en cuenta que el nombre de la tabla es "campos" y el nombre de la base de datos es "campos.db"

Te sugiero como buena práctica que agregues directamente las variables del script para creación de la tabla y del nombre de la base de datos.

```
package com.android.proyectoconexionsqlite.DB;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBconexion extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "campos.db"; //"dbPrueba";
    private static final int DB_version = 1;

    /* Agregar estas variables.*/
    public static final String TABLA_CAMPOS_CREATE = "create table campos (_id integer not null, campo01 text not null, campo02 text not null);";
    public static final String TABLA_CAMPOS = "campos";

    public DBconexion(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //db.execSQL(DBmanager.TABLA_CAMPOS_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(TABLA_CAMPOS_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DBmanager.TABLA_CAMPOS);
          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLA_CAMPOS);
    }
}
```

Realiza estos cambios en tu clase `DBmanager` :

```
  package com.android.proyectoconexionsqlite.DB;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DBmanager {

    public static final String CAMPOS_ID = "_id";
    public static final String CAMPOS_CAMPONRO1 = "campo01";
    public static final String CAMPOS_CAMPONRO2 = "campo02";

    private DBconexion _conexion;
    private SQLiteDatabase _basededatos;

    public DBmanager(Context context) {
        _conexion = new DBconexion(context);
    }

    public DBmanager open() throws SQLException{
        _basededatos = _conexion.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        _conexion.close();
    }
}
```

**Es muy importante elimines los datos de tu app o elimines completamente la app instalada para que se vuelva a crear de nuevo la nueva base de datos y la tabla.**

Comment: Hola, he realizado los cambios en un nuevo proyecto y en esta linea
private static final String DB_NAME = campos.db; //"dbPrueba";
campos.db esta en rojo, por eso en mi primer codigo lo colocaba con comillas (""), sera que necesito crear una base de datos antes? o con este codigo se crea.

Comment: perdon deben ser comillas ya edite

Comment: sigue sin aparecer la carpeta en el nuevo proyecto, no comente que estoy usando un dispositivo virtual de android studio, escribí el mismo código que me proporcionaste  y cambie el nombre de la base de datos por si acaso pero sigue sin aparecer la carpeta. y el proyecto se ejecuta correctamente pero me sale esta linea en error E/cacionalumnosb: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

Comment: tendré que agregar la dependencia. implementation 'androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.2.0'? podria ser por eso creo

Comment: Todas las carpetas van a aparecer dentro del paquete de la app, no se va a permitir escribir afuera. Revisa que en el script de creación de la tabla debe existir un espacio  con el "(", debe ser ... campos ( ... . En cada prueba elimina antes la aplicación instalada por favor, de otra forma no se generará la nueva estructura-.

Comment: nada, sigue sin funcionar, elimine cada aplicacion anterior que tenia en el dispositivo, el query de la tabla le di un espacio para que este separado y sigue sin salir la carpeta de databases en el paquete, conoceras algun tutorial o un codigo funete que pueda probar? porque ya me quede estancado aqui

Comment: Indispensable el uso del LogCat, si deseas desarrollar en Android, el uso del LogCat puede ser la diferencia entre unos minutos a días, es importante revisar que mensaje se muestra en el LogCat.